# How to Highlight Countries on a World Map with Different Colors in react-svg-map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm currently working on a project where I need to highlight specific countries on a world map. By default, the countries are displayed in light blue, but I want to change the color to dark blue for the highlighted ones. The library I'm using has documentation with examples showing multiple colors, but there's no accompanying code.

I tried adding the **selectedLocationIds** property but i do not how it works in this case.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import { CheckboxSVGMap } from "react-svg-map";

<CheckboxSVGMap
map={world}
className="h-[350px] w-full map-class"
onLocationMouseMove={onLocationHover}
onLocationMouseOut={() => setSelectedCountry(null)}
/>
```

Below is the map i am getting:
[image]

But i want this with only two colors like below:
[image]

Comment: You  don't need any js / react code for this, just use css `:hover`.

Comment: @MisterJojo hovering is working, but i want to set some countries selected(highlighted) in the map.

Comment: so you can add / remove any css class (with yours colors) on yours svg chosen elements....

Comment: @MisterJojo can you please give an example how can I?

Comment: no problemo, but it would be preferable if you showed here a minimum of the SVG code you are using, as is recommended here in the guidelines of this site...